# What is the name of the John Woo movie that has this telephone caller id tracing battle scene?

Tags: identify-this-movie

The main scene I remember is that some kidnappers do a sophisticated setup (which they are kind of proud of) to avoid tracing of the caller id. Basically they set up a battery of anti-tracing devices - like 6 in a row.

The people of the kidnapped victim (some asian-mafia guys) await the call from the kidnappers and have already installed 7 anti-anti-tracing devices - thus when the kidnappers call they are indeed able to trace the caller id ...

The movie is pretty much non-hollywood, asian/hongkong action style, probably 80ies, early nineties.

I watched it in the mid-90ies on a VHS rental tape in Europe. I think it is by John Woo, but could not identify it via the information provided by IMDB (I am positive it is not 'The Killer').

I remember vaguely that the kidnapping was somehow staged (the victim is somehow with the kidnappers) - and that the movie contains quite a humoristic story level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you are referring to is [The Big Hit (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120609/)

Directed by Kirk Wong starrring Mark Wahlberg.

The phone trace you are referring is the infamous "Trace Buster"

Comment: Awesome catch! (btw, it was [produced by John Woo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Hit), at least)